# How do I create an JS Object with methods and constructor in ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, clojure, interop, clojurescript

Imagine the task is to create some utility lib in clojurescript so it can be used from JS.

For example, let's say I want to produce an equivalent of:

```
    var Foo = function(a, b, c){
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      this.c = c;    
    }

    Foo.prototype.bar = function(x){
      return this.a + this.b + this.c + x;
    }

    var x = new Foo(1,2,3);

    x.bar(3);           //  >>  9
```

One way to achieve it I came with is:

```
    (deftype Foo [a b c])   

    (set! (.bar (.prototype Foo)) 
      (fn [x] 
        (this-as this
          (+ (.a this) (.b this) (.c this) x))))

    (def x (Foo. 1 2 3))

    (.bar x 3)     ; >> 9
```

**Question: is there more elegant/idiomatic way of the above in clojurescript?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was solved with [JIRA CLJS-83](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-83) by adding a magic "Object" protocol to the deftype:

```
(deftype Foo [a b c]
  Object
  (bar [this x] (+ a b c x)))
(def afoo (Foo. 1 2 3))
(.bar afoo 3) ; >> 9
```

Comment: Note the timestamp. This answer actually came after the one by dnolen on Jan 26, 2012 (about a year later), and this seems much more elegant.

Answer (score 12):

```
(defprotocol IFoo
  (bar [this x]))

(deftype Foo [a b c]
  IFoo
  (bar [_ x]
    (+ a b c x)))

(def afoo (Foo. 1 2 3))
(bar afoo 3) ; >> 9
```

Is the idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, it looks idiomatic in fact but you can't call from js, (we are building js lib):

    cljs.user.afoo.bar(3)   

where we can:

    cljs.user.x.bar(3)

In order to use your idiomatic version from js side one have to call:

    cljs.user.afoo.cljs$user$IFoo$bar(null, 3)

Am I missing something?

Comment: @user535149 that's a different question really. If you want to export something use (defn ^:export foo [..] ...)

Comment: ^:export works as long as 'something' is a function. I want to export an object whose methods are defined on its prototype.

Comment: That won't be very useful since the methods on the prototype will be namespaced.

Comment: So, what would be idiomatic clojurescript way to create an object with constructor, with methods on prototype? Is is the way I proposed in my original question the only one?