# deftype vs. defrecord

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

While `defrecord` is the preferred form -for the general case- in Clojure for defining an "entity", in ClojureScript one can find far more references to `deftype`, as reflected in [various](http://himera.herokuapp.com/synonym.html) [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9021998/569050).

What is the difference between both forms? Which should one prefer?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`deftype` creates a bare-bones object which implements a protocol.

`defrecord` creates an immutable persistent map which implements a protocol.

Which to use depends on what you want. Do you want a full ClojureScript data structure? Then use a record. Do you just want a bare-bones thing that does nothing but satisfy a protocol?  Then use a type.

The two bits of documentation you reference use types because they're trying to illustrate protocols at the most basic level, and types have less "going on" than records, so to speak.

However, most real-world uses of object-like things in Clojure/ClojureScript need to store fields of data along with the object, and for that you should emphatically use a record, for the same reason you should use any of Clojure's immutable collections.

Comment: according to the document and quick repl inspect, `defrecord` doesn't create map, `defprotocol` does. `deftype` and `defrecord` both create class with immutable fields [deftype doc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deftype), [defrecord doc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defrecord).

Answer (score 2):

According to [DEFTYPE VS DEFRECORD](https://lispcast.com/deftype-vs-defrecord/),
you should distinguish *programming constructs* and *domain constructs*.

`deftype` is for programming constructs and `defrecord` is for domain constructs that need a custom type.

Hope this helps.