# Fluent interface in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am doing a library in ClojureScript that will expose a public JavaScript API. Since it has to mimic the API of an existing JavaScript library, I would like to present the same kind of fluent API :

```
myLib.prepareToDo()
     .something()
     .and('also')
     .somethingElse()
     .run(function(err, result) {
         console.log("yay!");
});
```

In Javascript, one could create a fluent API like this [site point](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-like-boss-understanding-fluent-apis/)):

```
var MyClass = function(a) {
    this.a = a;
}

MyClass.prototype.foo = function(b) {
    // Do some complex work   
    this.a += Math.cos(b);
    return this;
}
```

I can then call it like :

```
var obj = new MyClass(5);
obj.foo(1).foo(2).foo(3);
```

Now, as far as I know, there is no notion of `this` in ClojureScript, although apparently it is possible to access it `this-as`.

I don't get how to use it though, hence my question.

How can I create a fluent interface in ClojureScript ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(defrecord)` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018326/how-do-i-create-an-js-object-with-methods-and-constructor-in-clojurescript) to the rescue. Extending the "magic" protocol `Object` to our record or type causes the defined methods to appear as member functions in the JavaScript object. To enable the "fluent interface", some methods return an instance of `MyClass`.

```
(defrecord MyClass [a b]
    Object
      (something [this] this)
      (and-then [this s] (assoc this :a s))
      (something-else [this] (assoc this :b (str a "-" a)))
      (run [this f] (f a b)))
```

Then we can have a JavaScript client like so:

```
var myClass = new my_namespace.core.MyClass();
myClass.something()
   .and_then("bar")
   .something_else()
   .run(function(a, b) { 
       console.log(a + " - " + b) });
```